# Get dimensions from a Base64-encoded image

Tags: javascript, image, base64

I have an Angular application where I need the dimensions of
an Base64-encoded image. I have tried to load it into an `Image`, but it just says it is `0x0`.

```
const image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,someBase64ImageString';

console.log(image.width + 'x' + image.height);
```

How can I get this information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The step between setting the `src` and the image being in a "loaded" state (thus having dimensions) is asynchronous - this seems to apply to data URIs as well as external resources (at least in Chrome).

To safely guarantee the `width` and `height` are populated, logic should be run in a callback. I.e.,

```js
let im = new Image;
im.src = 'data:image/png;base64,whatever';
im.onload = () => console.log(im.width);
```

Note this is only an issue the first time an image is loaded. Your code works as is for successive calls. Presumably, this has something to do with the way the browser is processing and caching the data.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. As far as I recall the onload event is fired when the page is loaded, but since it's already loaded when i register, I cannot see when this event should be fired?

Comment: Images have their own `load` event.  A page being "loaded" only considers the markup - not the state of embedded resources.  The point is  loaded or not, there's obviously some processing going on intended to be non-blocking before the image dimensions get populated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you prepend src with `data:image/png;base64,`

So it should be

`img.src= 'data:image/png;base64,' + b64string;`

Comment: It was prepended i had not thought to show that in my question. I will fix that right away :) Thanks!

Comment: I would make sure that the image is a valid image then - the code you posted works https://i.imgur.com/hetNNxT.png

Comment: Unfortunately it is. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Odd, that's not a valid image for me. V8 engine says that it is not a valid B64 encoded jpeg, and when I convert it back to a jpeg it says that it is corrupted. I think that's your problem. What are you using to encode it to b64?

Comment: I think the pastebin i used messed something up. I tried decoding it myself and it went fine ( http://imgur.com/a/FzuIU)

Comment: Yeah it must've, I tried it again with the site it used and it returns an error. Could you upload the image and I'll try b64 encoding it?

Comment: I have tried doing it in my console like you did and it works there with the image I have been using